# Remove White space around image - CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get image from odoo database to show the image into div background, but my image has white space around it, so i need to remove this white space to apply div background image,

Mycode :

```
<div  t-attf-style="text-align:center;background:url('/web/image/event.event.ticket/#{doc.event_ticket_id.id}/image_medium') no-repeat; 
               font-size:#{doc.event_ticket_id.font_size}px;width:50%;height:900px;float:left;background-size:500px 900px;display:table;">
                  <span style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;display:table-cell;" t-esc="doc.name"></span>

                </div>
```

[image]

How to remove white space around images using CSS ?

Comment: Can you maybe provide some code that we can run here? With a link to your image etc

Comment: What you need is `background-size: cover;`, go check [your options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?v=control).

Comment: @skobaljic i have tried but its not working,

Comment: Please anybody help me to solve this

Comment: @US-1234 can you provide a link to the image you want as background-image?

Comment: Yes Please share image link or any similar image to work on.

Comment: @xxCodexx Added image

Comment: image itself have white space? @US

Comment: Yes images stored in DB has white space @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: probably you need to remove white space in image. Otherwise if you want to remove in css try background-position to remove white spaces

Comment: Is the white the same size every time or is it changing for each image?

Comment: @Merschi Will change for each image

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try one of these code's:

```
img{vertical-align:bottom}
```

or

```
img { vertical-align: top; }
```

or

```
html, body {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```css
.main{
text-align:center;
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQPzy.png') no-repeat; 
font-size:12px;
width:50%;
height:900px;
float:left;
background-size:500px 900px;
display:table;
background-position:-50px -35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <span style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;display:table-cell;"> Content</span>

                </div>
```

But you have to know size of white space of images. Then you can (-) the position.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something. Please check it this works fine for you. Here I have tried to set background position and background size. Rest everything can vary like div's width and height.

```css
.back{
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQPzy.png');
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-size: 130% 150%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-position: 42% 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="back"></div>
```